# iOS Launch Screen Image not always showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xib, launch

I use a Launch Screen (xib) in my app to overcome the problem of the resizeable screen, since i don't always want add Launchscreens everytime, Apple create a new iPhone with a different screen resolution.

In my launchscreen, i placed a UIImageView directly in the center of the view using constraints. The image shows the logo of the company i work for.

The problem is, that sometimes the image is being hidden (mostly after install and first launch) and sometimes it shows (mostly after a view times using it). I'm not quite sure, what the problem is. Is it because at the first-launch-time(s) it has to load many ressources?

Comment: if possible then send the image of what you set in constrain ??

Comment: Please remove Launch Screen (xib) and also targets->General->App icons and launch images in clear your Launch screen file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem: It seems, that if there isn't enough disc space left on the device, it doesn't show the xib's (Launch-Screen's) Image. iOS at some point clears out some disc-space (i guess from NSLibraryDirectory)  and than the images show again.

If this is a major problem to any of your apps, use Launch-Images instead.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer isn't correct. I have 29 GB of 64 GB used and still seeing this issue.